# Using OpenCV with python for ios apps

Tags: python, ios, opencv, computer-vision, computer-science

I am looking for ways to write an OpenCv program using python that detects objects in real time for an ios apps. Thus, it's probably going to be a mobile web application since i am using python. Now is there a way to initialize the ios cams like than of an iphone to get a live video feed. Normally in desktop applications OpenCV will initialize the desktop cam upon 
cam = cv2.videocapture(). how about for ios devices, when creating mobile web apps?